# creating active state arrow in navigationbar

Tags: html, css

I have this code in my CSS file:

```
.blog-nav li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 500;

}

.blog-nav li a {
color: #fff;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
font-weight: 500;
color: #cdddeb;
}

.blog-nav li a:hover,
.blog-nav li a:focus {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

I would like to add an arrow like this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/blog/.

I tried with this code from the basic template from bootstrap:

```
/* Active state gets a caret at the bottom */
.blog-nav li a .active {
  color: #fff;
}
.blog-nav li a .active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i saw from your code, the .active class is not a selector of anchor tag, which means the .active is a child of anchor tag, not state class, i hope i understood you well

so it should be like this

```
/* Active state gets a caret at the bottom */
.blog-nav li a.active {
  color: #fff;
}
.blog-nav li a.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

read more about [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)